# How do you prove your traffic to potential advertisers?

Tags: traffic, measure

Potential advertisers always ask me how much traffic my website has, the number of unique visitors, etc. I have all these stats but I would like more transparency (otherwise how do they know I haven't enhanced the stats?).

Is there a website which does that (ie simply measuring the traffic - nothing fancy) so that I could tell potential advertisers to check my stats on that website. This way it would be completely transparent. I imagine I would have to install a javascript file (from their server) on my website so that they can measure my traffic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Quantcast? That's exactly what they do and it's free too.

Link: http://www.quantcast.com

Comment: who downvoted this and why?

Answer (score 3):

Quantcast is a great solution, but if you want more control over your data, I think Piwik would offer you a great solution (ok I'm a bit biased, being part of their team, but it is awesome). You can create a profile for your advertisers and they can check the stats themselves, or you can create an iframe with the specific stats, on a secure page which they can check at their leisure. You can check out a demo of Piwik at http://demo.piwik.org

Comment: Being a big fan of piwik myself, how exactly does this add, as Anthony's request, "more transparency" to his site stats for advertisers, seeing how I can just go and change whatever value I want in the DB?

Comment: Because the customer can access the stats themselves. He can even use a multi-tracker and provide them with data specific to his needs. The other solutions are not as transparent in how they gather info. For example Alexa uses panel and toolbars. Not exactly a vey robust process for accuracy. Quantcast can be gamed, or analytics solution can be gamed. Why I suggested Piwik is that depending on the setup, it can be very transparent.

Comment: and can be gamed as well. even easier so as i just have to login to my mysql and enter whatever value i want...

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I agree with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the online advertisers I have used have used Alexa ranking as a rough estimate how much traffic my site receives.

Google, Alexa, Quantcast and all other stat based programs can be faked using plenty of proxies. The real test is checking your rankings and ensuring that your being found on certain 'KEYWORD PHASES' they will want to be targeting. Stats are easy to fake, Google Results are not.

Answer (score -2):

Why not add them as a user to that Analytics profile and let them see your stats for themselves after signing an NDA. I wouldn't believe any other service that's estimating your stats without access to an account.

If i'm going to spend money advertising on a website I'm not going to believe any site estimating your traffic other than one which has a tracking snippet installed and one which has been there for at the least 6 months. I would want to see how much organic traffic, and referral traffic you get as well as page views.

If you inflated your own traffic it would probably show a big spike at some point in direct or strange referral traffic.